# Contar Valores Duplicados

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Necesito hacer un conteo de los valores duplicados de un campo. Tengo la siguiente Query:

```
SELECT [GRADO DE RIESGO POR CREDITO],COUNT([GRADO DE RIESGO POR CREDITO]) AS ABC
FROM FINREP.dbo.[CALIFICACION_SOFOM.CALIFICACION]
GROUP BY [GRADO DE RIESGO POR CREDITO]
```

Que me da esta salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hecho esto busco hacer un "UPDATE" en un determinado registro con los valores duplicados. He intentado con esta query:

```
UPDATE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT_2 SET NUMERADOR = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FINREP.dbo.[CALIFICACION_SOFOM.CALIFICACION] HAVING COUNT(*)>1) WHERE ID_KQI = '003-RCDAT_D011-2';

SELECT * FROM Parametria.DBO.TABLA_INPUT_2
```

Sin embargo me trae como salida 338 valores,  deberían ser 337 pues hay un registro que no se duplica

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrían decir que estoy haciendo mal en mi Query

De antemano gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto:

```
SELECT [GRADO DE RIESGO POR CREDITO],
       COUNT(1) AS ABC
       FROM FINREP.dbo.[CALIFICACION_SOFOM.CALIFICACION]
       GROUP BY [GRADO DE RIESGO POR CREDITO]
       HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Te recupera solo las filas que tienen duplicados, por lo que solo deberías contar las mismas así:

```
SELECT SUM(T.ABC)
       FROM (
            SELECT [GRADO DE RIESGO POR CREDITO],
                   COUNT(1) AS ABC
                   FROM FINREP.dbo.[CALIFICACION_SOFOM.CALIFICACION]
                   GROUP BY [GRADO DE RIESGO POR CREDITO]
                   HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
       ) T
```

Finalmente anidas todo en la sentencia de actualización:

```
UPDATE Parametria.dbo.TABLA_INPUT_2 
       SET NUMERADOR = (
              <la consulta anterior>
       )
       WHERE ID_KQI = '003-RCDAT_D011-2'
```